# node react firebase chat application offline

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have gone through firebase documentation, I am able to configure chat application with the streaming cloud, wondering if we can able to achieve offline msg system with firebase. 
1 If the user is not online msg will b delivered to him and when he logged in unread msg count will be visible.  
2 if the user is offline, can we send that msg to his email id?

[image]

Comment: for (2) do you mean "if the user sending the message is offline?"

Comment: Yes, if user is offline, online user can able to send that message to hia email id